# Css relative position

Tags: css

How can I set the top position of a div 30*n. N is the number of div inside the outer div (And all that without javascript). For exemple.

```
#div1
{
    top:#div1>numberOf(div)*30+"px";
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Without javascript? Is this homework?

Comment: With javascript /or/ jQuery it's easy. With CSS is ... AFAIK impossible. First of all, you should use `CLASS` for your 30 elements, not `ID`: ID is unique-per-page. !

Comment: Seriously, do the divs have special properties like do they need to be overlapping, or you have reasons why you can't set them all to a fixed height and with fixed margins, so that they end up where you want them all by themselves?

Comment: I'd love to help but your question is too vague. Mathematical calculations cannot be in CSS statements. But depending on what you're trying to do there may be other ways to achieve your desired effect. A simple diagram or mockup would go a long way in improving this question, if you want us to put in effort, it would be nice to see some effort from you first! :)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ulovor/edit#javascript,html,live @AndrewDunn : completely agree with you

Comment: Badger Attack!!! http://jsfiddle.net/c4Cxp/

Comment: Too vague? I don't see that. The question is very clear on what the OP wants.

Comment: He hasn't even concretely mentioned if he's using `position: relative` or `position: absolute` "relative position" could mean anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform any calculations within CSS. The closest thing to what you want is to use PHP to edit inline CSS.

For example:

```
<?php $answer = result of calculation ?>
<div id="div1" style="top: <?php echo $answer; ?px">...</div>
```

I can't think of anyway of getting the answer without using javascript.